# Using bower to install 3rd party modules into a yeoman generated Angular application is not working - nothing is rendered, no errors either

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, bower

I am having trouble including some 3rd party modules in my Angular application, where their inclusion causes the page to render nothing.  This is occurring for 2 different modules, and I have tried 2 different angular generators (angular-generator and cg-angular), so it makes me think I am doing something wrong.

Here is an example for the [timer directive](https://github.com/siddii/angular-timer). I run this command from the application root and confirm the package was installed in the bower_components directory:

```
bower install angular-timer
```

I add this line to index.html to source the directive:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-timer/dist/angular-timer.min.js"></script>
```

I inject it into my application in app.js:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['timer']);
```

Then when I load the page (grunt serve), the page is completely blank, and the console reports no errors.  The network tab of the Chrome developer tools shows that the angular-timer.min.js script is indeed loaded.

It seems straightforward, but clearly something is wrong and I am not sure how to further debug it given that no errors are raised.

The platform is Linux Mint 16 x64 btw.

Any ideas most welcome!

Comment: In the GitHub page, it says to run "bower install angular-timer"

Comment: Thanks Omar, a mistake in the question which I've corrected. The package is downloaded and exists.

Comment: Did you put the <script .."angular-timer"../> tag after the line in which you put the <script .."angular.min.js"/> tag?

Comment: I didn't consider that but, yes, it is below the angular.js script.  (Also the path and filename are correct with no typos hence a 304 on the network tab and not a 404, the script is found and loaded.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using yeoman basically you should include the modules in your app.js correctly. As I see from your link the directive requires extra modules to run I think since it has requirements sessions. Make sure that you satisfy all the requirements.